# What characters should this regex cover

Tags: regex

```
\\s*[\\-]?[\\d]{1,3}\\s+[\\-]?[\\d]{1,3}\\s+[\\-]?[\\d]{1,3}\\s+[\\-]?[\\d]{1,3}\\s*
```

I have this regex for taking in 4 coordinates which are whole numbers (positive or negative). Can you please suggest any bugs in this regex?

Comment: Is it not working for any cases?

Comment: What language is this being used in? Java?

Comment: Are you experiencing a specific problem with it? It sounds like no, you're simply asking for someone else to review its correctness, in which case it may be a better candidate for [codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a Java regex, then it's correct for matching a string that contains four integer numbers between -999 and 999, separated by whitespace. It's very ugly, though, and could be simplified a lot:

```
\\s*(?:-?\\d{1,3}\\s+){3}-?\\d{1,3}\\s*
```

If it's not Java, then you only need one backslash at a time (but you might need other syntax, depending on your language).

Comment: When you say ugly? Does it only mean in appearance or as in performance and everything?

Comment: Mostly appearance: Violation of the DRY principle and unnecessary use of character classes are the two main problems. Whether performance is worse depends on how smart the regex engine is in figuring out what it can optimize away.

Comment: What does the part with the question mark and colon mean?

Comment: @Vish: That's a non-capturing group. `(?:...)` groups the contents between the brackets into a single token which can then be repeated: `(?:...){3}` - so now three of the four numbers plus delimiters can be matched in one go, without having to type that part of the regex three times.

Comment: Oh, thanks for that. I get why my code looks dirty now. Thanks once again.